# PHP if-else always showing else after mysql_num_rows equal to 1

Tags: php, mysql, forms, authentication

I have a form named `login` that when is submitted sends the fields `username` and `password` to a MySQL database to check if they match. I want to `echo` an error when they don't match.

Here is the PHP code that goes above the form:

```
if (!isset($_POST['login'])) {
    mysql_connect (...);
    mysql_select_db (...);

    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $location = $_POST['location'];

    $username = stripslashes($username);
    $password = stripslashes($password);
    $username = mysql_real_escape_string($username);
    $password = mysql_real_escape_string($password);

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM members WHERE username='$username' and password='$password'";

    $result = mysql_query($sql);

    if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 1) {
        session_register("username"); 
        session_register("password"); 
        header("Location: $location");
    }
    else {
        echo "Wrong username or password.";
    }

    mysql_close();
}
```

And the form:

```
<form name="login" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
    <input name="location" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $_GET['location']; ?>"/>
    <input name="username" type="text" value="Username" onclick="this.value=''"/>
    <input name="password" type="text" value="Password" onfocus="this.value='';this.type='password'"/>
    <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Login"/>
</form>
```

If I submit the form with the correct username and password the code works normally.

The **problem** is that the error message is always present, even before the form is submitted. Any ideas?

Comment: I do not see how "If I submit the form with the correct username and password the code works normally." when you say in first line if (!isset($_POST['login']))

Comment: I figured the only conclusion can be that $_POST['login'] is not used in this script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change first line to :

```
 if (isset($_POST['username'])) {
```

Answer (score 3):

```
if (!isset($_POST['login']))
```

remove the exclamation mark. So `if (isset($_POST['login']))`

Comment: Although it's logical, without the exclamation mark the form doesn't work even with correct username/password.

Comment: Hmmm. Is that all your code or there's more? Can you please post all then?

Answer (score 0):

$_POST['login'] is most likely not set in your script. The aforementioned solution will fix your first bug. Yet, you will not be able to login if $_POST['login'] is not set.

I suggest you check for the post variables that you will use in your script:

```
if(isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password']) && isset($_POST['location'])) {
// your code
}
```